# Selenium with Python not able to fully open the website

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have tried the following code and tried to open the website as mentioned:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"..\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://example.com")
```

The website opens with the Chrome Browser but not with the Selenium using Python.

Please let me know what should I do to open the website completely.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM None till now. Else I would have mentioned it. Please can you attempt it on your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run it with chrome options. I am able to launch your application with below code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "chromedriver path"
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_experimental_option(
    "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
option.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=option)


url = 'https://example.com'

driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
sleep(20)
```

**output:**

[image: output image]